# What is the best way to implement the instruction fetching step in a MIPS program using java?

Tags: java, assembly, mips

I am implementing a simple MIPS simulator using java. My problem is in the fetching instruction step where I should take one instruction and convert it to 32-bit binary code to be able to determine that the first 6 bits are the opcode and the next 5 are the rs(source register) and so on.

At first I thought I would just make an arraylist and add the 15 instructions my program is going to support and then make another arraylist and add the 32 registers available and then when the user enters his code I loop on the entered string comparing it with my instructions and registers names in the arrays, but then I realized I don't know which characters exactly I am going to compare from the users code I mean (add $s1 $s4 $s5) will be different from (addi $t8 $zero 1) so I can't just check the substring of the first 3 characters every time with the instructions array and then check the next 3 because as you see the zero register might take a larger place and so on.

My second approach is to define the instructions by their opcodes and the registers by their binary values then convert the given instruction by the user to binary and compare it. Is there any other possible or probably easier ways to do so?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. The fetch normally operates on machine code already, not assembly code. So you already have the numbers you can mask and compare. Otherwise, if you want to process assembly code, you should tokenize it using the spaces and commas etc. as separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, your question is how to get from the user's assembler code to the machine code that is interpreted by your MIPS. This is where tokenizers come in handy. Use a StringTokenizer (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to convert user input into a string of byte code and feed the latter one to your MIPS exactly how you propose in your question.